# Complex regex match with various patterns

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with a column containing the following information:

```
    c("GYRA.Flq_NC_002695.1.916822_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRA_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"GYRB.CARD_pvgb_AP009048_3760295_3762710_ARO_3003303_Escherichia_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRB_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"MARR.CARD_pvgb_U00096_1619119_1619554_ARO_3003378_Escherichia_Multi_drug_resistance_MDR_regulator_MARR_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"PARC.Flq_M58408_gene_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_PARC_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"SOXS.CARD_pvgb_U00096_4277468_4277933_ARO_3003381_Escherichia_Multi_drug_resistance_MDR_regulator_SOXS_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"TOLC.CARD_phgb_FJ768952_0_1488_ARO_3000237_tolC_Multi_drug_resistance_Multi_drug_efflux_pumps_TOLC", 
"parE.CARD_pvgb_NC_007779_3172159_3174052_ARO_3003316_Escherichia_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_parE_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"GYRA.Flq_CP001918.1_gene3562_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRA_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"PARC.Flq_NC_003197.1.1254697_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_PARC_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"GYRA.Flq_NC_003197.1.1253794_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRA_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"parE.CARD_pvgb_NC_003197_3343961_3345854_ARO_3003317_Salmonella_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_parE_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"ACRR.CARD_pvgb_NC_014121_1270697_1271351_ARO_3003374_Enterobacter_Multi_drug_resistance_MDR_regulator_ACRR_RequiresSNPConfirmation"
)
```

What I want to do is to fetch the specific ID number within each of the entries above, marked below, and create a new column with this number for each row in the data frame.

"GYRA.Flq_**NC_002695.1.916822**_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRA_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"GYRB.CARD_pvgb_**AP009048_3760295_3762710**_ARO_3003303_Escherichia_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRB_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"MARR.CARD_pvgb_**U00096_1619119_1619554**_ARO_3003378_Escherichia_Multi_drug_resistance_MDR_regulator_MARR_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"PARC.Flq_**M58408**_gene_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_PARC_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"SOXS.CARD_pvgb_**U00096_4277468_4277933**_ARO_3003381_Escherichia_Multi_drug_resistance_MDR_regulator_SOXS_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"TOLC.CARD_phgb_**FJ768952_0_1488**_ARO_3000237_tolC_Multi_drug_resistance_Multi_drug_efflux_pumps_TOLC", 
"parE.CARD_pvgb_**NC_007779_3172159_3174052**_ARO_3003316_Escherichia_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_parE_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"GYRA.Flq_**CP001918.1**_gene3562_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRA_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"PARC.Flq_**NC_003197.1.1254697**_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_PARC_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"GYRA.Flq_**NC_003197.1.1253794**_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_GYRA_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"parE.CARD_pvgb_**NC_003197_3343961_3345854**_ARO_3003317_Salmonella_Fluoroquinolones_Fluoroquinolone_resistant_DNA_topoisomerases_parE_RequiresSNPConfirmation", 
"ACRR.CARD_pvgb_**NC_014121_1270697_1271351**_ARO_3003374_Enterobacter_Multi_drug_resistance_MDR_regulator_ACRR_RequiresSNPConfirmation"

I have tried the following command:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ref_name2 = sub("[A-z]+.[A-z]+.[A-z]+.([A-z][A-z].[0-9]+.[0-9].[0-9]+)", "\\1", ref_name),
         ref_name2 = sub("\\_ARO.*", "", ref_name2),
         ref_name2 = sub("\\_Fluoro.*", "", ref_name2),
         ref_name2 = sub("\\_gene.*", "", ref_name2))
```

But this only partially matches the above strings, and also removes a few of the letters that I want to have. Is there a simpler way to do this than multiple sub/gsub calls?

What I want to end up with:

```
c(NC_002695.1.916822, AP009048_3760295_3762710, U00096_1619119_1619554, M58408, U00096_4277468_4277933, FJ768952_0_1488, NC_007779_3172159_3174052, CP001918.1, NC_003197.1.1254697, NC_003197.1.1253794, NC_003197_3343961_3345854, NC_014121_1270697_1271351)
```

I have tried to match it visually at https://regexr.com/30u4a, and also tried to read a lot about complex matching, but can't seem to find the correct code.

Comment: `[A-z]` **is not the same as** `[A-Za-z]` you know?  I'm afraid that's not what you want.  `[A-z]` will include the characters `[`, `\ `, `]`, `^`, `_` and `\`` char in the range.  As your data is plagued with `_` chars, I think that will interfere with your seach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
> sub("^.*?_([A-Z]+[0-9_.]*[0-9]).*", "\\1", x)
 [1] "NC_002695.1.916822"        "AP009048_3760295_3762710"  "U00096_1619119_1619554"    "M58408"                    "U00096_4277468_4277933"    "FJ768952_0_1488"          
 [7] "NC_007779_3172159_3174052" "CP001918.1"                "NC_003197.1.1254697"       "NC_003197.1.1253794"       "NC_003197_3343961_3345854" "NC_014121_1270697_1271351"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Bmmja/3).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string (can be omitted, since `sub` is used)
- `.*?` - zero or more chars, as few as possible (note it is not possible to use `[^_]*` here as the pattern we need may appear after 0 or more underscores)
- `_` - a `_`
- `([A-Z]+[0-9_.]*[0-9])` - Capturing group 1:

  - `[A-Z]+` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters
  - `[0-9_.]*` - 0 or more digits, `_` or `.` chars
  - `[0-9]` - a digit
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I could do was [this example](https://regex101.com/r/1sQqYS/3):

```
"[A-Za-z]*\.([A-Za-z]*_)*([A-Z]+_?\d+(_\d+(_\d+)*|\.\d+(\.\d+)*)?)[^"]*"
```

that means, search for the left double quote `"`, then a group of letters, then a dot `.`, then a variable number (possibly empty) of sequences of letters (any case) followed by underscores `_`, and then the group we are interested in (group `\2`):

- a sequence of letters, followed (optionally) by an underscore, followed by

  - a sequence of groups of digits, separated by underscores, or
  - a sequence of groups of digits, separated by dots `.`.

and this followed up to the next double quote, closing the string.

if you do a global substitution by the following string:

```
\\2
```

then you'll have the desired result you posted, as can be seen in the demo above.